# WIX - Custom actions - Making them happen during a UI install only?

Tags: .net, wix, wix3

I have a custom action that I want to only run, during a UI install of my application.

If I have the following WIX xml :

```
<Custom Action="SetEnableMyNewFeature" After="SetSetEnableMyOldFeature">(NOT ENABLEMYNEWFEATURE) AND (((UILevel = 4) OR (UILevel = 5)) AND INSTALLING)</Custom>
```

Which doesn't seem to act as I want it to.

I need it to run when doing a UI install (not command-line, or repair)

Comment: Include this custom action to `InstallUISequence` only.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to get it working with the InstallUISequence tags either.

Comment: Any errors? How exactly is it "not working"?